# Add new 'x' number of columns in data frame using max value in specific column using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas DataFrame, as below:
[image]

From such DataFrame I want to generate the following output:

[image]

To obtain the required DataFrame I used below code.

```
first_list_len_max = df1['first_list_len'].max()
```

It gives me the maximum number of columns I need add in data frame then I manually added 4 columns like below.

```
df1[['1_','2_','3_','4_']] = pd.DataFrame(df1.first_list.values.tolist(), index= df1.index)
```

Here I need some automated method to add numbers of columns using `first_list_len_max`.

**Remark**: `first_list_len_max` value may change each time.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
first_list_len_max = df1['first_list_len'].max()
L = [f'{i}_' for i in range(1, first_list_len_max + 1)]
df1[L] = pd.DataFrame(df1.first_list.values.tolist(), index= df1.index)
```